# Use Webpack to prevent globals being created when importing an old library

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using Webpack and have to deal with importing an old AMD library that uses the `define()` call.

This is okay, but in the script, it sets `window.VeryOldLibary = VeryOldLibary` allowing global access.

I have tried using the `import-loader` to replace the `window` global without success.

How can I tell webpack to run the script in a closure and shim `window` for something else so nothing gets polluted in the global scope?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader?